# Is it possible to get the content of current window into a background service

Tags: android, background-service

I am a newbie in android development, so please pardon me if this question is too basic. I want to develop a service which runs in the background and collects all the text data that is currently on the screen of the device. I have figured out how to run a background service forever. However, I have no clue that how I will collect all the text data that is currently on the screen of the device. Even if there is not a direct method, I am ready to follow any trick or indirect/longer path. In the end, all I want is that I am able to get the text data in my background service.

Answer (score 0):

Being a third party data app you can not read content of window .

You may use [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to retrieve window content in your application. Of course user has to give permission to your app.As original doc says :

```
Window content may be retrieved with AccessibilityEvent.getSource(), findFocus(int), getWindows(), or getRootInActiveWindow().
```